# Angular 4 form crashes on being created

Tags: angular

I am trying to create this form in Angular 4 in a dialog menu. The problem is whenever the form is created, it immediately crashes with error message:

```
ERROR Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.
```

Also, The input tag loses focus as soon as I start typing(in other words, I can't type in my input at all)

I have tried commenting out relevant code but nothing happens

HTML Code:

```
<form [formGroup]="saveForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()" novalidate>
        <div class="columns medium-12 small-12 row-margin">
            <div class="row row-margin">
                <label for="testPlanName" class="columns medium-4 small-12">Test plan name : </label>
                <input alloy type="text" class="alloy-input columns medium-8 small-12" [(ngModel)]="save.testPlanName" formControlName="testPlanName"
                    name="testPlanName"> //This is where it crashes.
            </div>
            <div class="row row-margin">
                <div class="columns medium-4 small-12">How would you like to create : </div>
                <div class="columns medium-4 small-12 radio-group">
                    <div class="row align-middle">
                        <div class="column shrink">
                            <div class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" id='optionNew' name="createOption" value="New version" [(ngModel)]="save.createOption" formControlName="createOption" 
                                    (click)="setCreateOption('New version')" /> //This is where it crashes.
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column foundation-column-gutter-removal">
                            <label for="optionNew">New version</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row align-middle">
                        <div class="column shrink">
                            <div class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" id='optionOverwrite' name="createOption" value="Overwrite existing" [(ngModel)]="save.createOption" formControlName="createOption"
                                    (click)="setCreateOption('Overwrite existing')" /> //This is where it crashes.
                                <span></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="column foundation-column-gutter-removal">
                            <label for="optionOverwrite">Overwrite existing</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="columns medium-12 small-12 section-footer">
            <input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="save.projectId" formControlName="projectId">
            <input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="save.testPlanId" formControlName="testPlanId">
            <button alloy-button default type="submit" [disabled]="!saveForm.valid">Save</button>
            <button alloy-button default mat-dialog-close elementFocus>Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Typscript Code:

```
export class SaveDialogContentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public saveForm: FormGroup;
    // tslint:disable-next-line: no-any Reason-Any is used for form data-types
    public save = {} as any;
    public dialogType: string;
    public projectData: string;
    public testPlanData: string;

    // Subscriptions
    private getProjectDataSubscription: Subscription;
    private getTestPlanDataSubscription: Subscription;

    constructor(// tslint:disable-next-line: no-any Reason: data type is unknown and can be anything*/
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public saveType: any,
        private testService: TestService
    ) { }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.dialogType = this.saveType.content.type;
        this.initializeForm();
        this.save.createOption = 'New version';

        if (this.dialogType !== 'new') {
            this.projectData = this.saveType.content.projectData;
            this.testPlanData = this.saveType.content.testPlanData;

            setTimeout(() => {
                this.getTestplanDetails(this.projectData);
                this.testService.setProjectData(this.projectData);
                // tslint:disable-next-line align no-magic-numbers Reason: aligment for settimeout
            }, 500);
        }

        this.getProjectDataSubscription = this.testService.getProjectData().subscribe((data: string) => {
            this.save.projectId = data;
        });

        this.getTestPlanDataSubscription = this.testService.getTestPlanData().subscribe((data: string) => {
            this.save.testPlanId = data;
            this.getTestplanDetails(data);
        });
    }

    public getTestplanDetails(testId: string): void {
        this.testService.getTestPlanHeaderWithTestId(testId).subscribe(
            (data) => {
                if (data) {
                    this.save.testPlanId = data.id;
                    this.save.testPlanName = data.name;
                    this.save.projectId = data.projectId;
                }
            }
        );
    }

    public initializeForm(): void {
        if (this.dialogType === 'new') {
            this.saveForm = new FormGroup({
                'projectId': new FormControl(this.save.projectId, [Validators.required]),
                'testPlanId': new FormControl(this.save.testPlanId),
                'testPlanName': new FormControl(this.save.testPlanName, [Validators.required]),
                'createOption': new FormControl({ value: this.save.createOption, disabled: true })
            });
        } else {
            this.saveForm = new FormGroup({
                'projectId': new FormControl(this.save.projectId, [Validators.required]),
                'testPlanId': new FormControl(this.save.testPlanId),
                'testPlanName': new FormControl({ value: this.save.testPlanName, disabled: true }, [Validators.required]),
                'createOption': new FormControl(this.save.createOption)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *I have tried commenting out relevant code but nothing happens* because it was not relevant. Besides - I see no `setCreateOptions` nowhere which supposedly is causing ECAIHBCE

Comment: @Antoniossss What I meant was I couldn't pin-point where the problem is... and can you provide an example or link to what you are suggesting?

Comment: I didnt suggest anything yet.

Comment: I meant the setCreateOptions thing you mentioned

Comment: Thats one of yours onclick methods. Did you copy-paste that code from somewhere or something? It looks like you don't know your own code.

Comment: Oh.. well I didn't post it here because it was working fine. The problem is right where the form is created.

Comment: the problem may be related to the fact that you subscribe to observables which need to set form data. there is an issue that the values of some fields may change after the form is initialized and then the form goes crazy since the value changed unexpectedly. I would suggest aggregating the data for initialization first and then initializing your form with the aggregated data.

Comment: You have commented that as troublesome line so dont blame me for your mistakes.

Comment: @Divneet I tried hard-coding form controls (removing the observables) but the problem still persists.

Comment: @Antoniossss this is my first time posting a question.... will be more cautious from next time